# How to update global object

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron, nightmare

Iam trying to run an external function inside `nightmarejs` evalute function...As you can see my code below...

```
function get_my_links(url){
    vo(function* () {
    var nightmare = Nightmare();    
    var href_link = []; // i have tried making it as global without var but did not work
    var title = yield nightmare
    .goto('https://examply/'+url)
    .evaluate(function (href_link,url,get_my_links) {
        $('.myclass').each(function() {
            href_link.push($(this).attr("href"));
        });
        if($.isNumeric($("#someid").val()))
        {
            get_my_links(1)
        }
        else{
            return href_link;
        }
    },href_link,url);
    console.log(title);
    yield nightmare.end();
    })(function (err, result) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    });
}

get_my_links(0)
```

By above code I am trying to update `href_link` ...
1) How to make it Global object,so that everytime the function is called new value should be added with the existing values?

Comment: As per the code comments, you tried without adding var, just try declaring with `var href_link = []; ` outside the function and then `function get_my_links(url)`

Comment: tried adding it outside... but `evaluate`  detects as undefined `href_link`

Comment: Why not use a local variable and provide it as the argument to a `callback` function? It did not work for you probably because it is an async call and the global variable was not updated immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st The reason 
      `// i have tried making it as global without var but did not work`
is not working because though you making the object global but every time you call get_my_links function, it will update the global object to empty array.

For your use case, define href_link before defining get_my_links function. Like

```
var href_link =[];
function get_my_links() {
...
}
```

Defining href_link after function definition like ->

```
function get_my_links() {
...
}
var href_link =[];
```

will throw an error of undefined value of href_link inside get_my_links function due to hoisting which must be the case you have mentioned in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

electron uses node.js, so you can use the global object of node.js to store the value.

https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

When you use this solution you should be able to access the value also from other parts of your app.